# Does an increase in SR lead to an increase in strength and intensity of ionospheric lightning?

Tags: meteorology, solar-terrestrial-physics, electromagnetism, upper-atmosphere, ionosphere

As explained in the following document:

[ELF Electromagnetic Waves from Lightning: The Schumann Resonances](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjww4al9v_yAhWAJTQIHRhPC5IQFnoECAsQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2073-4433%2F7%2F9%2F116%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw09QtbhsPTQ4HLyl8yEexBG)

Upper-Atmosphere phenomena like Sprites and Elves can be recorded with extremely low frequency detectors. Hence, is it valid to assume than an increase in magnitude of the Schumann Resonance will lead to an increase in upper atmosphere phenomena intensity and frequency? After all, these are side-effects of the emission of electromagnetic radiation of thunderstorms.